# TypeError: app.auth() is not a function? (React App)

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I'm adding authentication to a react app I'm working on with a basic signup page and firebase. I have a firebase.js, a Signup.js, and an AuthContext.js. I have my Signup component, Auth Context and signup comp functionality done, and it should be working in a basic way at this point, but I'm now getting an error that says:TypeError: app.auth is not a function. It's referring to the export from my firebase.js file. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

firebase.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});

export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

Signup.js:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";

export default function Signup() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
  const { signup } = useAuth();
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords do not match");
    }
    try {
      setError("");
      setLoading(true);
      await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to create account");
    }

    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        Already have an account? Log in
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

App.js:
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Container
        className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
        style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
      >
        <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
          <Signup />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "firebase": "^9.6.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In web version 9 your code should be like this

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in firebase 9, the imports have changed, so in my firebase import, I had:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/auth";
```

and it should be:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
```

adding compat solved it.